# How to store jwt token in localStorage C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jwt

I am using old patterns to store data in cookies, now I want to shift things to local storage, how it can be done using c#.

How to store data in localstorage using c# ?

Comment: You can use javascript to store data in localstorage but i doubt there is way to store data to localstorage using c#.

Comment: may be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52001888/7262120

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7301611/7262120

Comment: This link may help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561877/is-it-possible-to-set-localstorage-or-session-variable-in-asp-net-page-and-read